# Connecting Slack, Api.ai & Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, slack, dialogflow-es

I know exactly what I want to achieve, but need some help to be able to start.

Flow:

1. Automatic periodic checking of my gCalendar to see if I just finished a meeting
2. Sending message to Slack with question "What is to-do list after the meeting?"
3. User writes a response.
4. Response get stored in Google Sheet.

My main concern right now are steps 1 and 2: is Api.ai capable of automatic periodic checking of my gCalendar *by itself*, so when my meeting is over, I get message in Slack and then I can continue normal communication with the Api.ai bot?

The problem I see here is that I expect Api.ai to push a message to Slack after some external trigger instead of waiting trigger from me as a Slack user.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so, you may want to check [Bot Users](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) which enable teams to conversationally interact with external services or your custom code by building bot users.

**What can bot users do?**

> The primary way bot users interact with people on a given team is by connecting to the Real Time Messaging API (RTM API for short) and opening up a websocket connection with Slack.
>
> The Events API is an alternative way to receive and respond to events as a bot user contained within a Slack App. Instead of connecting over a websocket, you subscribe to specific events and messages and Slack sends them to your server.

Secondly, you may want to also check the Bot implementation given in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-slack-bot) or you may try to customize your bot behavior using the following steps:

1. Clone the repository https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-slack-bot
2. Change the code to `index.js`
3. In the Docker, use the `run` command specifying the full path to the directory containing the `index.js` file:

run command:

```
docker run -d --name slack_bot \
           -e accesstoken="Api.ai client token" \
           -e slackkey="Slack bot user key" \
           -v /full/path/to/your/src:/usr/app/src \
           speaktoit/api-ai-slack-bot
```

Lastly, for additional information, please also see [Slack Integration documentation](https://docs.api.ai/docs/slack-integration) wherein it gives guidelines on how you can set up Slack Integration in API.AI. Please also see [Slack Help Center](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/206329808-Connect-Google-Calendar-to-Slack) for ways on how you can connect Google Calendar to Slack.